# Laravel shows blank page as the view

Tags: php, laravel, view

I have created a function in my `HomeController.php` beside the `index` method in `Laravel 5.3`. In the index method, there are some data retrieved from database, and the sent to the other method to be analyzed and sent to the `home view` to be shown.
My problem is that laravel displays a mere blank page instead of the actual `home.blade.php` view. Below is the code that I am using to retrieve data from database and send them to the view. Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

```
public function index ()
{
    $user_table_data = DB::table($table_name)->get();           
    $this->ChooseAction($user_table_data);
}

private function ChooseAction ($r_value)
    {

        foreach ($r_value[0] as $key => $value)
        {
            if ( $key !=='id' && $value !== '0' )
            {
                array_push($this->choose_action_result, $key);
            }
        }        

        if (!empty($this->choose_action_result))
        {
            return view('home', ['rvalue' => $this->choose_action_result]);
        }else{
            return view('home');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Changing the `cooseAction` method from `private` to `public` did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your index method return the call of private value

```
public function index ()
{
    $user_table_data = DB::table($table_name)->get();           
    return $this->ChooseAction($user_table_data);
}
```

mark the return keyword in the call statement if should return the view

Comment: Dear sir, forgive me about mu dumbness. I added the return to the `index` method and nothing has changed. Should I have done something else in addition to that?

Answer (score 1):

This will be your code:

```
public function index ()
{
    $user_table_data = DB::table($table_name)->get();           
    return $this->ChooseAction($user_table_data); //here you also need a return
}

private function ChooseAction ($r_value)
{

    foreach ($r_value[0] as $key => $value)
    {
        if ( $key !=='id' && $value !== '0' )
        {
            array_push($this->choose_action_result, $key);
        }
    }        

    if (!empty($this->choose_action_result))
    {
        return view('home', ['rvalue' => $this->choose_action_result]);
    }else{
        return view('home');
    }

}
```

You didn't return the view in your `public function index() {}` that you got from your private method.

Comment: Dear sir, forgive me about mu dumbness. I added the return to the `index` method and nothing has changed. Should I have done something else in addition to that?